# Show div based on select option value

Tags: jquery, select

I have 5 divs for example

```
<div class="group" id="div1">Div1</div>
<div class="group" id="div2">Div2</div>
<div class="group" id="div3">Div3</div>
<div class="group" id="div4">Div4</div>
<div class="group" id="div5">Div5</div>
```

Then I have a select control:

```
<select id="mySelect">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

Then what I want to do: when "3" is selected in mySelect control, I want to display the first 3 divs, when "5" is selected, I want to display all divs. Additionally, the initial value of select is for example "2", then when a page is load, I want to display first 2 divs. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I've tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/234/ so far, however I don't know how to show for instance 2 first divs when "2" is selected in select control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the divs are in the order of the options, you could use the [`:lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/) selector jQuery offers:

```
$('.group').hide();
$('#mySelect').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('.group:lt(' + ($(':selected', this).index()+1) + ')').show();
});
```

You could then add the following code to select the second one on load:

```
$('#mySelect option:eq(1)').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

Here's [the edited fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByZ7x/). This has the (in my opinion pleasant) side-effect of not having to use ID's at all.

Answer (score 0):

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/xWn2B/) should do what you want.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();

    // Show selected number of boxes
    $('.group').slice(0, parseInt($('#selectMe').val().replace('option', ''))).show();

    // Change number of divs shown when select is changed
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {  
        var howMany = parseInt($(this).val().replace('option', ''));
        var divs = $('.group');

        divs.hide();

        divs.slice(0, howMany).show();
    });
});
```

Here, we use [`$.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to split the array of `.group` divs selected by `var divs = $('.group');`

This line:

```
$('.group').slice(0, parseInt($('#selectMe').val().replace('option', ''))).show();
```

is pretty condensed, but it essentially does the same as the code inside the `$.change()` function, just shorter.

Answer (score 0):

```
$().ready(function () {
  // Cache selectors. We don't need to traverse the DOM on every run.
  var $divs = $('.group'),
      $select = $('#mySelect'),

  // Create a named function. I think it's nicer than having a lot of
  // anonymous functions, and allows for better re-use if the need should
  // arise.
  toggleVisible = function (event) {
    var numVisible = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $divs.hide().filter(function (index) { return index < numVisible; }).show();
  };

  // Trigger the callback on change.
  $select.on('change', toggleVisible);
  // For the initial page load, trigger the handler manually.
  $select.trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZGc7/

**UPDATED**: Utilize `slice`, since it is much nicer than `filter` in this case:

```
$().ready(function () {
  // Cache selectors. We don't need to traverse the DOM on every run.
  var $divs = $('.group'),
      $select = $('#mySelect'),

  // Create a named function. I think it's nicer than having a lot of
  // anonymous functions, and allows for better re-use if the need should
  // arise.
  toggleVisible = function (event) {
    var numVisible = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    $divs.hide().slice(0, numVisible).show();
  };

  // Trigger the callback on change.
  $select.on('change', toggleVisible);
  // For the initial page load, trigger the handler manually.
  $select.trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BZGc7/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/vsbkg/

```
var showDiv = function(goal){
    var count = 1;
    $('.group').each(function(){
    if(count <= goal){
        $(this).show().nextAll('.group').hide();
    }

        count = count +1;
    });
};

var goal = $('#mySelect').val();
showDiv(goal);

$('#mySelect').change(function(){
       showDiv($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: [`$.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) makes things much easier here, although this works well when the `<select>`'s value is an integer, which it isn't in the JSFiddle linked to by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/cadence96/TXYgD/2/

It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:
:)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        var nr = $(this).val().replace(/option/,'');
        $('.group').hide().filter(function(){
             return $(this).index()<nr;
        }).show();      
    }).val('option2').trigger('change');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/235/

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just prevAll, nextAll and current element to accomplish what you want. Just my version.. [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/JSyLV/236/) here

Below function should do the trick,

```
var $select = $('#selectMe');
function showHideDiv() {

    var selectedVal = $select.val();
    $('#' + selectedVal ).prevAll('.group').show(); // <-- show all prev
    $('#' + selectedVal ).show();                   // <-- show current
    $('#' + selectedVal ).nextAll('.group').hide(); // <-- hide all next

}
```

Complete code

```
var $select = $('#selectMe');

$(document).ready(function () {
    $select.change(function () {
        showHideDiv();
    });

    showHideDiv();
});

function showHideDiv() {

    var selectedVal = $select.val();
    $('#' + selectedVal ).prevAll('.group').show(); // <-- show all prev
    $('#' + selectedVal ).show();                   // <-- show current
    $('#' + selectedVal ).nextAll('.group').hide(); // <-- hide all next

}
```